# What is the significance of Virus Cycles?

Tags: ps3, dead-nation

I've been playing some Dead Nation recently and have noticed that each time I complete a level, I am presented with some statistic about the percentage of the current "Virus Cycle". Snooping around the web, I've managed to gather that this is a [not-so-straight-forward measurement](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Store-Games/Dead-Nation-and-the-Virus-Cycle/m-p/12041268/message-uid/12041268/highlight/true#U12041268) of how many zombies were killed by players in each country.

What I didn't manage to find is any concrete data as to whether or not increasing the amount of cycles has any effect other than making players in that country feel good about themselves (each time the cycle reaches 100%, a new cycle begins, so if some country gets to 100% on cycle 2, it would start at 0% on cycle 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to one of the users in the thread you linked, sounds like you get rewarded with artwork for playing in certain cycles, though it does not seem to effect gameplay.

Other searches for information about virus cycles have not come up with anything else.

Comment: Silly of me to have missed that. I'll give this question a little while longer (on the off chance anyone has any hands on experience on the matter) and then go ahead and accept yours.

Comment: Also, before you have unlocked some of the artwork, if you go to the art page and select an image you don't have (mostly the latter ones) it says something like "play the game during different virus cycles to unlock this" on some of them.